# Как вставить строку в базу?

Tags: sql

[image: Каким запросом можно вставить строку для каждого ID]

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким sql запросом можно вставить строку 'rich_editing','true' для каждого ID. Первый столбец автоинкремент, уникальный

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO tablename (userid, metakey, metavalue)
SELECT userid, 'rich_editing', 'true'
    FROM tablename
```

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось.

Comment: @Петр Отметьте, пожалуйста, данный ответ как принятый (зелёная галочка слева от ответа), если он решил ваш вопрос.